# Java random distribution

Tags: java, random, distribution

I have an array of Objects which is [36] long. I have to randomly distribute these objects between owners, one object can only have one owner. The user can set 2 - 5 owners and it goes like this:

- 2 owners - 14 Object / owner - 8 Object without owner
- 3 owners - 10 / owner - 6 empty
- 4 owners - 8 / owner - 4 empty
- 5 owners - 6 / owner - 6 empty

I want to ask for example in case 2 how can i set 6 random Objects owner to 0 (without owner), and 10 random Objects for each owner?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to accomplish, and surely you can be more specific than "didn't work"?

Comment: The distribution of objects to owners is unclear from your description. Also, whatever problem you are having is not clear. Please provide a more detailed description.

Comment: I tried to phrase it differently.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear from the question what you are trying to accomplish, but you can achieve some shuffling with the `Collections.shuffle()` function.

```
int[] shuffle = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };

List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i : shuffle) {
    intList.add(i);
}

Collections.shuffle(intList);

System.out.println(intList);
```

One possible result:

```
[1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1]
```

**References:**

[shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved
First i created a 2d array which contains the 4 different case

```
public int[][] shuffle = {{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
                          { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
                          { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4},
                          { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}};
```

Then in a method i copied out the needed row to a new array based on user input. I used Fisher - Yates shuffle on the primitive 1d array and looped threw the Objects where i called a setter methor for each owner.
Looks like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++){
   int helper = shuffle1d[i];
   objectArray[i].setObjectOwner(helper);
}
```